# Server Rack, Power Strips and UPS

Tags: electrical-power, ups, server-room

I would like to get rid of all the messy power cords behind our server racks by using short power cords (1's and 2's) with multiple power strips connecting to two different UPSs on separated circuits. I am also aware of the operating currents that are being drawn from the servers and will distribute the loads accordingly.

My question - the power strips are rated 15A with built-in circuit breaker. I assume this will be a problem due to "inrush" currents when servers are starting. Would it be better to instead use strips without built-in breakers when they are connected to UPS? Are there better alternatives if the aim is to minimize the number of long cords?

Thanks,

-T

Comment: could you help me out, it looks for me that your specially speaking in US-Metrics?
However 15A should be usually enough to power any normal powersource since it could hold at 230V 3450VA (+/- a bit)

Comment: How many servers are connected to a UPS  and what power rating does the UPS have ? You cannot make max current determinations without considering these factors. General server UPSes can range from 750VA to 5000VA+.

Comment: Would you not be better off using C14 power strips (depending on your layout, 2 vertical ones or multiple horizontal ones like https://www.amazon.com/Kenable-Power-Distribution-Unit-Horizontal/dp/B00X8F82L8/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=c14+pdu+19%22&qid=1568965104&s=gateway&sr=8-9?  If inrush current is going to blow fuses, you don't have adequate power, and chances are you would blow an upstream fuse if you did not have fuses on the PSU.   I would not recommend relying  on it, but most servers have (in the BIOS) the ability to delay starting so you can spread this load.

Comment: @davidgo good idea +1 from me